Content of my library doesn't update when i upload a new version on PyPI
I've tried to upload a newer version of my library with some fixes and it went alright. There were no problems with publishing itself. Then, I installed this version and encountered the fact that the module code hasn't updated at all. The description of library on PyPi page also remained the same, even though the README.md file was edited. I have waited enough time and tried a few times to make sure that there is no problem on PyPI side
I have found a question on the similar problem here but there was no relevant answer on it: PyPI: Module code doesn't update when I upload a new version
At first, to publish the library, I launched this command to create a distributive:
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

Then, uploaded to PyPI with this:
twine upload --repository pypi dist/*

It has always been fine with earlier versions and changes in library contents were immediate. I even tried to edit the content of build  folder manually, replacing old library modules, which were somehow put there automatically after  the first command, with new ones. It looks like this is the main problem.

Then, I installed this version and encountered the fact that the module code hasn't updated at all What is the exact command you used to install it?

The one which is listed on libraries page on PyPI: pip install ==
